# Shouldn't there be a copy ctor invocation here? Elision disabled (no named return value optimization)

Tags: c++, move, copy-constructor, copy-elision, nrvo

```
struct Test {
    int field = 30;
    Test() { cout << "In ctor" << endl; }
    Test(const Test &other) { field = other.field; cout << "In copy ctor" << endl; }
    Test(Test &&other) { field = other.field; cout << "In move ctor" << endl; }
    Test &operator=(const Test &other) { field = other.field; cout << "In copy assignment" << endl; return *this; }
    Test &operator=(Test &&other) { field = other.field; cout << "In move assignment" << endl; return *this; }
    ~Test() { cout << "In dtor" << endl; }
};

Test get_test() {
    Test t;
    return t;
}

int main() {
    Test t2 = get_test();
}
```

I think this is the canonical NRVO example. I'm compiling with `-fno-elide-constructors` and I see that the following are called: ctor, move ctor, dtor, dtor.

So the first ctor call corresponds to the line `Test t;`, the move ctor is constructing the `t2` in `main`, then the temporary that is returned from `get_test` is destroyed, then the `t2` in `main` is destroyed.

What I don't understand is: shouldn't there be a copy ctor invocation when returning by value? That is, I thought that `get_test` should be making a copy of `t` and then this copy is moved into `t2`. It seems like `t` is moved into `t2` right away.

Comment: Copy elision is mandatory beginning with C++17. The compiler is not allowed to call a copy constructor here. The code should compile even if `Test` is not copyable, only movable.

Comment: Oh cool, didn't know that! I compiled with C++14 (just out of curiosity) and now get: ctor, move ctor, dtor, move ctor, dtor, dtor. I'm still not sure I understand that. I know `t` can be moved into the return value since it is going out of scope soon anyway but I thought the whole point of disabling elision is that without elision, returning by value is a copy, not a move.

Comment: `get_test()` returns a temporary. Initializing from a temporary would call move constructor where available. That's kinda the whole point - it it weren't used for this, what would it be used for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### C++17

Starting from C++17, there is [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations) which says:

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. The **objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to**. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> - In the **initialization of an object, when the initializer expression is a prvalue** of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the variable type:

(emphasis mine)

This means that `t2` is constructed directly from the `prvalue` that `get_test` returns. And since a `prvalue` is used to construct `t2`, the move constructor is used. Note that in C++17, the flag `-fno-elide-constructors` have no effect on **return value optimization**(RVO) and is different from NRVO.

---

##### Pre-C++17

But prior to C++17, there was [non-mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Mandatory_elision_of_copy/move_operations) and since you've provided the `-fno-elide-constructors` flag, a temporary `prvalue` is returned by `get_test` using the move constructor. So you see the first call to the move ctor. Then, that temporary is used to initialize `t2` again using the move constructor and hence we get the second call to the move ctor.